# How to add extension for rails internationalisation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, internationalization

Right now I got rails app that works great with both languages. Eng and Rus.

But app is not representing language in url right now its: `example.com/posts` for both eng and rus, but I would need `example.com/ru/posts` and regular for english version `example.com/posts`

How can I do it?

routes file:

```
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'

  get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale
```

Answer (score 4):

[Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params) cover this case and provide examples.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def default_url_options(options = {})
  { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
end

# config/routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|ru/ do
  resources :books
end

get '/:locale' => 'your_root#page_action'
```